# iOS : transitionFromView - label in 'toView' not displayed

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, subview, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a strange error, when switching between two subviews in a UIView container. 
Note, that the two subviews is of same view controller type (same view), the only difference is the label, which is defined by a property.

When switching (animating) from box1 -> box2, the label text in box2 is not shown. But, if I besides setting the label text on box2, also change the background color of the view, the label text is shown after animation.

It seem to me, like there is an issue when drawing box2, when only the label text is being defined. How come?

**viewDidLoad**

```
// Define the to sub vies and the container
box1 = [[MyBoxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyBoxViewController" bundle:nil];
box2 = [[MyBoxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyBoxViewController" bundle:nil];
containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:PercentageGroupView.frame];

[containerView addSubview:box1.view];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

**viewWillAppear**

```
box1.title = "Box nr. 1";
box2.title = "Box nr. 2";
```

**segmentedControlChanged**

```
[UIView transitionFromView:box1.view
                    toView:box2.view
                  duration:1
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom 
                completion:nil];
```

Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 0):

So, I set up the following scenario:

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyBoxViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyBoxViewController *activeBox;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyBoxViewController *box1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyBoxViewController *box2;
- (IBAction)SwitchViews:(id)sender;
@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize activeBox;
@synthesize box1;
@synthesize box2;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Define the to sub views and the container
    [self setBox1:[[MyBoxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyBoxViewController" bundle:nil]];
    [[[self box1] view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [[[self box1] titleLabel] setText:@"Box Number 1"];
    [[[self box1] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];
    [self setBox2:[[MyBoxViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyBoxViewController" bundle:nil]];
    [[[self box2] view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [[[self box2] titleLabel] setText:@"Box Number 2"];
    [[[self box2] view] setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 200)];
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    [containerView addSubview:[[self box1] view]];
    [self setActiveBox:[self box1]];
    [[self view] addSubview:containerView];
}
- (IBAction)SwitchViews:(id)sender {
    if ([self activeBox] == [self box1]) {
        // switch from 1 to 2
        [UIView transitionFromView:[[self box1] view]
                            toView:[[self box2] view]
                          duration:1
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom 
                        completion:nil];
        [self setActiveBox:[self box2]];
    } else {
        // switch from 2 to 1
        [UIView transitionFromView:[[self box2] view]
                            toView:[[self box1] view]
                          duration:1
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom 
                        completion:nil];
        [self setActiveBox:[self box1]];
    }
}
@end
```

***MyBoxViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyBoxViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@end
```

***MyBoxViewController.m***

```
#import "MyBoxViewController.h"
@implementation MyBoxViewController
@synthesize titleLabel;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

Note that on my `ViewController.xib`, I added a `UIButton` which I tied to `-(IBAction)SwitchViews:(id)sender`.

The only thing that stands out to me is that when I activate the `[UIView transition...]`, the frames I set are maintained. I don't see anywhere in the code you provided where your frames are specified.

Other than that, in my code, I get a blue rectangle (20,20,200,200) and clicking the button flips it over to reveal an orange rectangle (40,40,200,200).

Does that help you?